# What is the original message bit string if N = 9 in forward error correction?

Tags: forwarderrorcorrection

The bit string below is a 54-bit message received from the channel. It is known to be Forward Error Correction (FEC) coded by a repetition code, in which the transmitted bit is encoded into N same bits.

101011010110110101010010000111100101011100010101100000

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers the Q cause you didn't mention your error correction algorithm.
But you can use this calculator in case it's hamming code: [Hamming calculator](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/FaultTolerantSystems/simulator/Hamming/HammingCodes.html)